# How to burst cache a react pwa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, progressive-web-apps

I have a react application bootstrapped with VITE. Anytime i push updates to production, i have to clear my browser cache, cookies and history to see the latest update. Below is my vite config file.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";

const manifestForPlugIn = {
    registerType: "prompt",
    includeAssets: [
        "favicon.ico",
        "apple-touc-icon.png",
        "masked-icon.svg",
        "favicon.png",
    ],
    manifest: {
        name: "My App",
        short_name: "PWA APP",
        description: "",
        icons: [
            {
                src: "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
                sizes: "192x192",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "favicon",
            },
            {
                src: "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
                sizes: "512x512",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "favicon",
            },
            {
                src: "/144x144.png",
                sizes: "144x144",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "any",
            },
            {
                src: "/96x96.png",
                sizes: "96x96",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "any",
            },
            {
                src: "/apple-touch-icon.png",
                sizes: "180x180",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "apple touch icon",
            },
            {
                src: "/maskable_icon.png",
                sizes: "512x512",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "maskable",
            },
        ],
        screenshots: [
            {
                src: "/screenshot-desktop.png", //update with desktop preview
                sizes: "800x600",
                type: "image/png",
                label: "Desktop Experience",
                purpose: "desktop",
                form_factor: "wide",
            },
            {
                src: "/screenshot-mobile.png", //update with mobile preview
                sizes: "400x800",
                type: "image/png",
                label: "Mobile Experience",
                purpose: "mobile",
                form_factor: "narrow",
            },
        ],
        theme_color: "#000000",
        background_color: "#ffffff",
        display: "standalone",
        scope: "/",
        start_url: "/",
        orientation: "portrait",
    },
};
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: "/",
    plugins: [react(), VitePWA(manifestForPlugIn)],
});
```

My sw.js file is auto generated by vite on production. I need users to see realtime updates.This is my first PWA build and i'm confused. I need help